# Magmi Base Image Getting Excluded

Tags: magento, magmi

we are using Magmi to import 500 products to our Magento 1.9 store.

Right now, everything works, except one single thing.

The base image is not getting included in the media gallery. We need this to show in media gallery too.

Everytime we import it, its excluded in the backend. 
And doesnt get listed on the media gallery too.

How do we fix this ?
Is there a one line SQL code to run on the phpmyadmin, so all the EXCLUDE selection is removed from all the products in the store ?

Or any Magmi fix for this ?

As per Magmi documentation, we need to put + in front, but that doesnt work with remote images. It shows warning.

Comment: There is a site dedicated to that tag now : http://magento.stackexchange.com/ , This question belongs there.

Comment: "It shows warning." - What's the warning message?